# Redirect requests fro fonts and icons to the main domain from a subdomain based on part of the URL path

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am having trouble loading fonts and icons hosted on main domain from subdomain.

Example:

I am on

```
sub.domain.loc/some/weird/path/desired/url/resource/to/load.extension
```

and I need to detect that /desired/url/ is in request and based on that redirect to:

```
domain.loc/url/desired/resource/to/load.extension
```

So far I failed getting 404 in the subrequest asking for that resource.
When I manually enter the desired url in address bar or edit request it succeeds and returns the resource. Given these circumstances I assume the problem is in redirection, so I googled a lot and found solution that is supposed to work, but it doesn't.

I am running Apache 2.4.18 with php7 on Xubuntu 16.04, my vhosts look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/domain/"
    ServerName domain.loc
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain/sub/www/
    ServerName sub.domain.loc
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)desired/url/(.*) domain.loc/url/desired/$2 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also what other stuff should I provide for the others to be able to determine the source of problem?

Comment: You should figure out why your subdomain is linking to fonts and icons at wrong URLs.   You need to fix it so that the redirect isn't used to load pages.

Comment: Your "redirect" is missing the _scheme_. However, as @Stephen has pointed out, a _redirect_ does not seem to be the solution to this problem.

Comment: Can you send me your link to investigate.<br> So i can recreate the website experience and the errors you see.<br> Thanks.

Comment: @Stephen Unfortunately i cannot avoid using the redirect, as i cannot mofify the original URL.
 <br /> 
DocRoot What do you mean by missing the scheme?
 <br /> 
jehovahsays Unfortunately the links i provided will have to be enough. They represnt structure of the url, they re just anonymized, because i am not allowed to share the actual URLs.

Comment: Docroot means that the scheme is missing because `domain.loc/url/desired/$2` should be `http://domain.loc/url/desired/$2`.

Comment: I tried previously using scheme and it did not change a thing.